# Azure ACR Auth Error - "aad access token with sp failed client id must be guid"

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-activedirectory, azure-cli

Using this guide: https://github.com/Azure/acr/tree/main/docs/preview/quarantine

**Endpoint to generate Token:**

GET https://quarantinetest1.azurecr.io/oauth2/token?service=quarantinetest1.azurecr-test.io&scope=repository:helloworld:pull,push

I am trying to authenticate with Azure ACR so that I can PATCH metadata for Image and remove it from Quarantine getting the following auth error:

"aad access token with sp failed client id must be guid"

I have tried to authenticate with Service Principal and Client Secret on this endpoint and Azure AAD Credentials encoded base64 also are not working getting same error

Answer (score 0):

By using encoded base 64 for authorization for client ID and secret this worked

```
$Auth_String =$client_id+":"+$client_secret
$Auth = [convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Auth_String))
```